# STL map composite

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int>> region;
    region[0].insert(make_pair(make_pair(1, 1), 1));
    return 0;
}
```

I am writing the above code and it don't work as expected, How can I fixed it? The error is " error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments"

Answer (score 3):

There is no specialization of `std::hash` for `std::pair`, so it can't be used as a key for `std::unordered_map` unless you provide a custom hash function.

Comment: You are awesome! After changing the "unordered_map" to "map" it works. Answer accepted